# How do I mark a GitHub repo as a template repo using the GitHub cli?

Tags: github-cli

I want to create a new repo using the GH cli tool. I want to mark the repo as a template repo.

NOTE:  I'm not trying to create a repo from a template, but rather create the repo AS a template.

I'm not finding settings in the cli tool for this setting.

Comment: The feature (to mark a repo as a template) does not seem to be available. See: https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/6cc7712583c9c012a158576666cf683506ab572a/pkg/cmd/repo/create/create.go

Comment: well that would explain why I'm not seeing it :-/